# Sql connection string for another pc

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I have an application that runs on SQL 2005 database 
I m trying to use same application on another machine same network,
I managed to log in on SQL 2005 using IP
Now I need to configure applications `app.config` file (found in visual studio solution) to allow connection

soo far I tried this connection string which isn't worked

this is what my config file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=ipaddress,1433;Initial Catalog=sample;User ID=sample;Password=sample;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is a `.config` file? Which language is your application written? Please, give us some extra details.

Comment: hey, my application written in asp.net and .config file is where you specify your SQL connection string.

Comment: Please insert this information in your question and tag it as `asp.net` too.

Comment: Is this other computer's firewall and SQL instance configured to allow incoming connections? (and, tell us what "doesn't work" - generally the server or client will return an error of some sort, which is helpful in troubleshooting...)

Comment: yes its all configured and SQL is connected on both computers.

Comment: You mean you can connect to the other computer's SQL instance via some other client (such as SSMS) using the tcp/ip protocol as you're trying to do here?

Comment: adding more details

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file. Rather then using an appSetting use the actual connectionStrings section.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=00.000.0.00,1433;Initial Catalog=taxi;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sample;Password=sample; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This string should work if anyone else got the same problem 
thanks everyone for looking and trying to figure it out with me

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=00.00.000.000;Initial Catalog=sample;User ID=sample;Password=sample;" />
```